# SAS Date issue with DBF imported file

Tags: date, import, sas, dbf

i'm importing a DBF file into SAS, which contains several date columns. I want to do some checks on some of these columns, such as:

- 1) DATA_NASC is > 01/01/1900
- 2) DATA_NASC is < today()
- 3) DATA_INI_V is > DATA_FIM_V

In my DBF file, the date columns are formatted as 'dd/mm/yyyy' (Brazilian standard format).
For instance, I have in my first row:

- DATA_NASC = 16/06/1940
- DATA_INI_V = 01/04/1995
- DATA_FIM_V = 01/04/2005

Below there's a snippet of the import of the DBF.

The idea is to create validation rules(a macro for each rule) to check the dates.

```
data inputs;
    call symput('campo1', "DATA_INI_V");
    call symput('campo2', "DATA_FIM_V";
    call symput('sistema2', "PVR_SUPERVIDA");
    call symput('hoje', %sysfunc(today(),ddmmyy10.));   
run;

filename inf "/folders/myfolders/BVP Data Quality/PVR_SUPERVIDA_201408.DBF";
proc dbf db4=inf out=test;
```

Now i wanted to do some simple SELECT COUNT(*) to count the total number of registers and the number of invalid registers. Something like:

```
proc sql print;
    SELECT COUNT(*) from test where &campo1 < '01/01/1900';
    SELECT COUNT(*) from test where &campo1 < '01/01/1900' and &campo1 > TODAY();
    SELECT COUNT(*) from test where &campo1 > &campo2;
run;
```

As my date columns in the DBF file are read as text in SAS, i can't manage to compare the values of the dates.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a proc contents result on your imported data set?

Answer (score 0):

After reading in your DBF file why not convert the date (character format) to an actual date format so you can then compare.

E.g:

```
realdate = input(mytextdatefield,date9.);
```

Comment: Hi,can you explain it a little further? which STEP should i do that? in the data step? And what is the result?

Comment: @BrunoCamiña well after you've imported your dbf file (I'm guessing through Proc Import?) Create another datestep to convert the dates e.g `data want; set importdate; convertedDATA_NASC = input(DATA_NASC, date9.);
convertedDATA_INI_V =input(DATA_INI_V,date9.);
convertedDATA_FIM_V = input(DATA_FIM_V, date9.); run;`

Comment: Here's what i'm doing: 
    filename inf &arq_in;
        proc dbf db4=inf out=test;

    data test2;
        set = test;
            convertedDATA_NASC = input(&campo2, ddmmyy10.);
    run;

    proc sql print;
        select convertedDATA_NASC from test2;
        select DATA_NASC from test;
    quit;

And here's what i'm getting as result:

convertedDATA_NASC
.

DATA_NASC
16/01/1847
16/06/1940
02/01/1956
03/12/1941
...

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. Could you help me? :(

Comment: I don't know what Macro values you're passing through but here is an end to end example that. I create a dummy dataset with dates as characters(text), Then in a next step convert them: `DATA fakeDBF; 
   INPUT charDates $ ; 
   DATALINES; 
16/06/1940
01/04/1995
01/04/2005
; 
RUN;
data convertedDates;
 format converted_charDates ddmmyy10.;
 set fakeDBF;
 converted_charDates = input(charDates, ddmmyy10.); 
run;
proc sql print; 
 select converted_charDates 
 from convertedDates; 
quit;`

Comment: Your code works perfectly with me. However, when I try to use the same structure, but importing a DBF file instead of writing the inputs with DATALINES, it doesn't work...  

I get a .  as output, although I have 500 rows in my database.

Comment: SOLVED!
I was using set = test; instead of set test;
I corrected it and it's working just fine.
Thanks